# Multiple table joins in Oracle SQL with same column names

Tags: sql, join

Currently I have 3 tables like below

Master

| ID_NUMBER | ZIPCODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12341 |
| 2 | 12342 |
| 3 | 12343 |
| 4 | 12344 |

Table1

| ID_NUMBER | CITYNAME | COUNTYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NEW YORK | QUEENS |
| 3 | DETROIT | SUFFOLK |

Table2

| ID_NUMBER | CITYNAME | COUNTYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ATLANTA | ROCKLAND |
| 4 | BOSTON | WINCHESTER |

My desired output is like below. I want to filter based on the zipcode from master table

| ID_NUMBER | ZIPCODE | CITYNAME | COUNTYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12342 | ATLANTA | ROCKLAND |

How would i go about writing a query for this? Below is what i have tried but it's giving me null values if the ID_NUMBER is not found on that particular table.

```
SELECT mstr.id_number,
       mstr.zipcode,
       t1.cityname,
       t1.countyname,
       t2.cityname,
       t2.countyname 
FROM MASTER mstr
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON mstr.id_number=t1.id_number
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON mstr.id_number=t2.id_number

WHERE mstr.zipcode='12342'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT mstr.id_number,
       mstr.zipcode,
       COALESCE(t1.cityname, t2.cityname) as cityname
       COALESCE(t1.countyname, t2.countyname) as countyname
FROM MASTER mstr LEFT JOIN
     Table1 t1
     ON mstr.id_number = t1.id_number LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON mstr.id_number = t2.id_number
WHERE mstr.zipcode = '12342
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can try since your tables are identical is to join `master` with the `union` of the tables

```
with t as (
    select Id_number, Cityname, Countyname
    from t1
    union all
    select Id_number, Cityname, Countyname
    from t2
)
select *
from Master m join t on m.Id_number=t.Id_Number
where m.zipcode='12342'
```

Comment: Thanks! My 2 tables are not identical. Some of the colums are different. I was just using the above example for reference!

Comment: I wasn't sure. even so, they don't have to be identical, only the columns used in the union - and only then the same data types.